# Shell command ${PWD/\/$upto\/*//$upto} not understood

Tags: linux, shell

I saw a shell function to change dir up to $upto.

```
upto() {
    cd "${PWD/\/$upto\/*//$upto}"
}
```

But I don't understand `"${PWD/\/$upto\/*//$upto}"`.
Could any one kindly explain?

The function was found in [an answer to a Unix & Linux Stack Exchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14309/54511).

Comment: Mmmmm, was the explanation [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14303/bash-cd-up-until-in-certain-folder#14309) not sufficient?

Comment: The function snippet you copied does not even work because there is no variable `$upto`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer? It turns out you can do lots of manipulations with variables beyone simply inserting them like you would with `$PWD`. Quoting from the [bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`
>
> The *pattern* is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. *Parameter* is expanded and the longest match of *pattern* against its value is replaced with string. If *pattern* begins with ‘`/`’, all matches of *pattern* are replaced with string. Normally only the first match is replaced. If *pattern* begins with ‘`#`’, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of *parameter*. If *pattern* begins with ‘`%`’, it must match at the end of the expanded value of *parameter*. If *string* is null, matches of *pattern* are deleted and the `/` following *pattern* may be omitted. If *parameter* is ‘`@`’ or ‘`*`’, the substitution operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If *parameter* is an array variable subscripted with ‘`@`’ or ‘`*`’, the substitution operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

So, in this example: `${PWD/\/$upto\/*//$upto}`

- *parameter* is `PWD`.
- *pattern* is `/$upto/*` (that's what the backslashes are for, to keep the slashes in *pattern* from ending the pattern prematurely, and to avoid turning on the "replace all matches" behavior you'd normally get from a *pattern* that starts with a slash)
- *string* is `/$upto`

So this looks in the variable `$PWD` (which the shell maintains as the current directory), finds the first spot in there where there's the directory name that's in `$upto` surrounded by slashes (so that setting `$upto` to "`dog`" won't find a directory named "`dogfood`"), and replaces that spot and the whole rest of the current directory by just "`/$upto`".